# Resolution of external monitors stuck at 1440x900 on Thinkpad T430 with Intel HD graphics

Tags: 14.04, resolution, xrandr, external-monitor, display-resolution

I'm working on my Thinkpad T430, with Intel HD4000 graphics chipset, in a 3-display setup (the laptop display and two external monitors). I accidentally pressed the `Super + P` combination, which cycles through display output modes. Even after cycling back to the original output mode, this has the unfortunate effect of limiting my external displays to a resolution lower than their native resolution. Any attempts to rectify this in `System Settings > Displays` are met with error messages like the following:

```
Could not set the configuration for CRTC 64

GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._gnome_2drr_2derror_2dquark.Code2: could not set the configuration for CRTC 64
```

Even xrandr, when attempting to set resolution for one of the displays with `xrandr --output HDMI2 --mode 1680x1050` merely returns `xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed`

Other answers around the net cite similar errors when having issues with the kernel version limiting their ability to use 3-display setups with Intel graphics, but those issues were fixed several releases back, and my setup *was* working fine until I pressed `Super + P` just now, which caused it to go a little haywire. How can I successfully restore the original settings?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved this issue in the following manner:

1. Navigate to `System Settings > Displays` again and select one of the external displays.
2. Disable that display and hit `Apply`. At this point you should only have 1 active external display.
3. Select the active display in the settings GUI and change its resolution to the preferred setting. It should apply successfully.
4. Re-enable the other display, and you may find (as I did) that it has automatically assumed the same resolution setting as your first external display did.

I was never able to get a clear answer as to what was causing this issue from a technical standpoint, but I was able to find a solution which I figured ought to be documented.